# cordova 2.9.x iOS 8 userAgent bug

Tags: ios, cordova, ios8

I am using Cordova 2.9.0 with phonegap to build an iOS app.
With iOS 8, I am getting error messages of

```
Deprecated attempt to access property 'geolocation' on a non-Navigator object.

Deprecated attempt to access property 'userAgent' on a non-Navigator object
```

I tried EddyVerbruggen's solution
https://gist.github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cd02c73162180793513e

But, I am getting those error messages from Cordova

Also, when my application loads completely, I have no problem using

```
window.navigator.userAgent
```

Comment: Hey Michael, I'm getting this as well. Have you made any discoveries around this issue?

Comment: I commented on the official ticket

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6911

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fist of all, it seems just a warning and the apps work fine.

They have been fixed this and I suposse it will be available soon, but for people using cordova 2.9.X, we have to change the `replaceNavigator` function to be like this on the `cordova.js` file (the whole else is new)

```
function replaceNavigator(origNavigator) {
        var CordovaNavigator = function() {};
        CordovaNavigator.prototype = origNavigator;
        var newNavigator = new CordovaNavigator();
        // This work-around really only applies to new APIs that are newer than Function.bind.
        // Without it, APIs such as getGamepads() break.
        if (CordovaNavigator.bind) {
            for (var key in origNavigator) {
                if (typeof origNavigator[key] == 'function') {
                    newNavigator[key] = origNavigator[key].bind(origNavigator);
                } else {
                    (function(k) {
                        Object.defineProperty(newNavigator, k, {
                            get: function() {
                                return origNavigator[k];
                            },
                            configurable: true,
                            enumerable: true
                        });
                    })(key);
                }
            }
        }
        return newNavigator;
    }
```